# anacondaをインストール完了。Djangoをインストールしたいけど…

Tags: python, windows, django, anaconda

コマンドプロンプトで

```
pip install django
```

と入力しても画像の通り

> 'pip'は内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド…

となります。

関係があるかわかりませんがpythonはアンインストールした方が良いというのを見たのでアンインストールしました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　画像の通り、とありますが画像が添付されていないようです。質問は後からでも「編集」より直せますので、再度アップロードを試していただけませんでしょうか。また、どの順番で何をしたのか、なるべく詳しく書いていただけるとありがたいです。現状だと質問者さんの環境が今どうなってるのかよく分からないです。おそらく質問者さんも困惑されているかと思いますが、冷静にひとつずつ、行ったことを箇条書きしてみてください。ヘルプ[「良い質問をするには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)も参考になるでしょう。

Comment: Anacondaとpipの併用は、よく理解している人しかやらない方が良いでしょう。[condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347) 目的に合っているか不明ですが、この辺の記事を参考にしてみてください。[Windows環境でAnaconda + Django REST Framework](https://qiita.com/TakayukiHatanaka/items/d59d2fd676d17816e40e), [vscodeでanaconda+djangoのチュートリアル【覚え書き】](https://qiita.com/arthur_1801/items/15bea5ea196d8afd1353)